# Simulate a random binomial sequence over n replications in R

Tags: r, matrix, simulation, resampling

I like to draw `nrep` times from a binomial distribution with theta parameter, to create one `k` length sequence for each theta, and build them in a matrix dimension `nrep x k`.  How can create a matrix of the results in R?

The code below draws (`nrep * k`) each from a different theta i.e sequence is not k length from same theta. [My aim is to draw nrep times a binomial probability theta length k.]

```
### simulate some binary sequence data in matrix ted (1000 x 20)
nrep <- 1000
s <- 7; k <- 20
theta <- rbeta(nrep, shape1=s+1, shape2=k-s+1)

ted <- 0
ted <- matrix(rbinom(k * nrep, 1, theta), ncol = k, nrow = nrep)
hist(ted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rbinom` is vectorized over parameter `prob`, so you can use `rep(theta, k)` to achieve

```
ted <- matrix(rbinom(k * nrep, 1, rep(theta, k)), ncol = k, nrow = nrep)
```

Comment: this is a great solution

Comment: @rrg, are you still looking for a more efficient or some other solution? Otherwise, accepting the answer and perhaps upvoting it would be appropriate.